# Override a function from a static library with MS coimpiler

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have a static lib that I use to link my final executable. This static lib internally defines and calls a function, something like `void texture::compress(void*, int)`. Now, I want to replace this function and replace it with my own code. If I simply define it, then I get multiply defined symbols link error. How can I make VS compiler/linker ignore it and use my override?

If it's possible to override like that, is it possible to call somehow version from the static lib? (I assume, this cannot be done, but who knows maybe there are some magic spells that could me it work?)

Comment: You can get its address, set RWX on memory page and replace its first opcode with JMP =). However, anti-viral spyware will go batshit crazy.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm No idea :) maybe it was something else, but autocomplete changed it.

Comment: @MinorThreat that's exactly what I needed, I just came up with this idea and wanted to update my question :) In my case it's my own simple code, and I'm ok to turn off AV if needed while working on this.